# Cannot Dynamically Add TextInputLayout Views

Tags: java, android, xml, android-textinputlayout

I want to populate TextInputLayouts based on the item that a user selects from a Spinner. Below is my XML (the ID with "CreatePollAnswer" is the view I want to populate dynamically):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/create_poll_linearlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.troychuinard.fanpolls.Fragment.CreateFragment">

<FrameLayout
    android:background="@drawable/image_border"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".525">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_image_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Click to Add Image" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".475">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/create_poll_question_editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="@string/create_poll_question" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/how_many_answers_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/how_many_answers_text"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/number_of_answers_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/create_poll_answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/create_poll_answer_editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
public class CreateFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private Button mAddImageButton;

private Spinner mSelectNumberofPollAnswers;
private String mSpinnerPosition;

private EditText mCreatePollQuestion;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

private View mRootView;

private TextInputLayout mCreatePollAnswer;
private EditText mCreatePollAnswerEditText;

public CreateFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment CreateFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static CreateFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    CreateFragment fragment = new CreateFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false);
    mAddImageButton = (Button) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.add_image_button);
    mSelectNumberofPollAnswers = (Spinner) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.number_of_answers_spinner);
    mCreatePollQuestion = (EditText) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.create_poll_question_editText);
    mCreatePollAnswer = (TextInputLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.create_poll_answer);
    mCreatePollAnswerEditText = (EditText) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.create_poll_answer_editText);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            R.array.number_of_poll_answers, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    mSelectNumberofPollAnswers.setAdapter(adapter);
    mSelectNumberofPollAnswers.setOnItemSelectedListener(new YourItemSelectedListener());



    return mRootView;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

public class YourItemSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(selected); i++) {
            ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.create_poll_linearlayout);
            TextInputLayout newAnswer = new TextInputLayout(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            newAnswer = (TextInputLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.create_poll_answer);
            newAnswer.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            layout.addView(newAnswer);

        }

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
   }
}
```

Here is the current error I am receiving:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:36)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:139)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:132)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:128)
                                                                                at com.troychuinard.fanpolls.Fragment.CreateFragment$YourItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(CreateFragment.java:153)
                                                                                at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:924)
                                                                                at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:913)
                                                                                at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:51)
                                                                                at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:883)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_darker</item>

    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/iron</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/iron</item>

    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_darker</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_darker</item>
</style>
>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

</style>


<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:titleTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.troychuinard.fanpolls">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".FanPollsApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/fan_polls_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> <!-- ADD THIS LINE -->
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".SignupActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.firebase.ui.GoogleClientId"
        android:value="@string/google_client_id" />

    <activity android:name="com.firebase.ui.auth.twitter.TwitterPromptActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.firebase.ui.TwitterKey"
        android:value="@string/twitter_app_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.firebase.ui.TwitterSecret"
        android:value="@string/twitter_app_secret" />

    <activity
        android:name=".PollActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_poll"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoadingActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Discussion_Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_discussion_"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".CreateActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Remove the `getApplicationContext()` call in the constructor call for the `TextInputLayout`. Just use `getActivity()`.

Comment: can you post your `styles.xml` files?
seems to me there's something in **AppTheme** as it says `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) ` in LogCat

Comment: I have updated the code. I prefer to use the theme NoActionBar, which inherits from an appCompat theme. I actually updated the theme in my CreateActivity, and I am still receiving the error.

Comment: As mentioned, change the `TextInputLayout` constructor call to `new TextInputLayout(getActivity())`. You also need to remove the line after that, as you can't re-add a `View` that's already there. I'm not sure what you wanted to do there. Just for testing, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml file add the following code inside the application  tag

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

Comment: What if I don't want to change the theme? I already have a custom theme set up that I want to use.

Comment: I have updated the code. I prefer to use the theme NoActionBar, which inherits from an appCompat theme. I actually updated the theme in my CreateActivity, and I am still receiving the error.